# 403 error - CSRF token in modal window

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot, bootstrap-modal, csrf

I'm working on a Spring Boot + Bootstrap project.
I've created a modal window to confirm the removal of itens, but after I added Spring Security to the project, the modal stopped working.

How can I properly configure the CSRF token in a modal window?
I have tried some approaches, with no success.

I get the following error when deleting itens:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403). Invalid
>   CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header
>   'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.

Thanks for the help!

confirmRemove.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmRemove" tabindex="-1"
    data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <form th:attr="data-url-base=@{/restaurants}" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Você tem certeza?</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <span>Are you sure you want to delete this restaurant?</span>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

</html>
```

restaurantpoll.js

```
$('#confirmRemove').on(
        'show.bs.modal',
        function(event) {

            var button = $(event.relatedTarget);

            var codeRestaurant = button.data('id');
            var nameRestaurant = button.data('name');

            var modal = $(this);
            var form = modal.find('form');
            var action = form.data('url-base');

            if (!action.endsWith('/')) {
                action += '/';
            }

            form.attr('action', action + codeRestaurant);

            modal.find('.modal-body span').html(
                    'Are you sure you want to delete <strong>'
                            + nameRestaurant + '</strong>?')

        });
```

RestaurantController (only the relevant part)

```
package com.matmr.restaurantpoll.controller;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

import com.matmr.restaurantpoll.exception.RestaurantNotFoundException;
import com.matmr.restaurantpoll.model.Category;
import com.matmr.restaurantpoll.model.Restaurant;
import com.matmr.restaurantpoll.model.filter.RestaurantFilter;
import com.matmr.restaurantpoll.service.RestaurantService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/restaurants")
public class RestaurantController {

    @Autowired
    private RestaurantService restaurantService;

    @Autowired
    public RestaurantController(RestaurantService restaurantService) {

        this.restaurantService = restaurantService;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public String delete(@PathVariable Long id, RedirectAttributes attributes) throws RestaurantNotFoundException {
        restaurantService.deleteById(id);

        attributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "The restaurant was successfully deleted.");
        return "redirect:/restaurants";
    }


}
```

restaurantList.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
    layout:decorator="Layout">
<head>
<title>Pesquisa de Restaurantes</title>
</head>

<section layout:fragment="conteudo">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="clearfix">
                <h1 class="panel-title liberty-title-panel">Pesquisa de
                    Restaurantes</h1>
                <a class="btn btn-link liberty-link-panel"
                    th:href="@{/restaurants/new}">Cadastrar Novo Restaurante</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">

            <form method="GET" class="form-horizontal"
                th:action="@{/restaurants}" th:object="${filter}">

                <div layout:include="MensagemGeral"></div>
                <div layout:include="MensagemErro"></div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input class="form-control"
                                placeholder="Qual restaurante você está procurando?"
                                autofocus="autofocus" th:field="*{name}"></input> <span
                                class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                                </button>
                            </span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-left col-md-1">#</th>
                            <th class="text-left col-md-2">Nome</th>
                            <th class="text-left col-md-3">Descrição</th>
                            <th class="text-left col-md-2">Categoria</th>
                            <th class="col-md-1"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr th:each="restaurant : ${restaurants}">
                            <td class="text-left" th:text="${restaurant.id}"></td>
                            <td class="text-left" th:text="${restaurant.name}"></td>
                            <td class="text-left" th:text="${restaurant.description}"></td>
                            <td class="text-left"
                                th:text="${restaurant.category.description}"></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-link btn-xs"
                                th:href="@{/restaurants/{id}(id=${restaurant.id})}"
                                title="Editar" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top"> <span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                            </a> <a class="btn btn-link btn-xs" data-toggle="modal"
                                data-target="#confirmRemove"
                                th:attr="data-id=${restaurant.id}, data-name=${restaurant.name}"
                                title="Excluir" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top"> <span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                            </a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="5" th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(restaurants)}">Nenhum
                                restaurante foi encontrado!</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

                </table>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div layout:include="confirmRemove"></div>

    </div>
</section>
</html>
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29509392/spring-boot-security-thymeleaf-and-csrf-token-not-injected-automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding **th:action="@{/restaurants}"** to the modal's form tag did the trick:

```
<form th:action="@{/restaurants}" th:attr="data-url-base=@{/restaurants}" method="POST">
```